# Hold, unhold feature for Twilio call which is already running

Tags: twilio, twilio-php

I've a Twilio call already routed to an agent via TaskRouter(Task, Reservation is already created, Agent has accepted the call) and now an agent needs Hold, unhold feature for the same Twilio call.
Can someone please provide best practice for this?
Can we do this by en-queuing a call to Workflow?if yes then, how should we redirect same call to the same agent for Un-hold feature?

Please let me know if anyone has code snippet available. I'm using PHP for this

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this one of a few ways but the basic process is:

First, provide Twilio some TwiML that places the call into "hold" then
when you're ready, use the CallSid of the call and the REST API to [redirect the live call](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/change-call-state).

```
<?php
// Get the PHP helper library from twilio.com/docs/php/install
require_once('/path/to/twilio-php/Services/Twilio.php'); // Loads the library

// Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/user/account
$sid = "YOUR_ACCOUNT_SID"; 
$token = "YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN"; 
$client = new Services_Twilio($sid, $token);

// Get an object from its sid. If you do not have a sid,
// check out the list resource examples on this page
$call = $client->account->calls->get("CALL_SID");
$call->update(array(
        "Url" => "http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml",
    "Method" => "POST"
    ));
echo $call->to;
```

To actually handle the "hold" you can use the [`<Enqueue>` verb](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/enqueue) as you guessed, placing the call into a call queue. Then when you are ready, redirect that call back out of the queue to a new experience.

Or you can use [`<Play>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/play) and set the `loop` attribute to zero, which tell Twilio to loop audio indefinitely. And again, redirect the call when you are ready to remove the hold.

Comment: Thank you for your response Megan, but can we track the whole end to end call for reporting after redirecting running call to a queue.?(ex. I've to track hold time of a call or the time call was put on hold queue by an agent etc)?

Comment: You can track `duration` on a call: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/call#instance-properties